# Want to hide char_limit in wordpress, and Read More tag should be appear there?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove **char_limit** from my code, and want to put there **Read More** tag

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking about wordpress posts then put this code in your function.php file.

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<div class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="view-full-post-btn">Read More</a></div>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more',11);
```

Comment: echo do_shortcode('[hms_testimonials group="1" template="13" order="id" direction="DESC" char_limit=1 ]');

I am using this, in our content file.
there is any solution for this?

Comment: i think u r using  plugin for this??

Comment: u r using hms testimonial wordpress plugin so u can read the documentation of that plugin or write to plugin author.

Comment: yes i am using plugin, but there is a mandatory field to mention char_length. there is another way to solve this?

Comment: what exactly u want?? u want a read more link then there is  setting for that in plugin.

In your WordPress dashboard navigation to Testimonials -> Settings.

Comment: i want to hide all data and read more link should be there, but problum is minimun char_length is must?